# uploading a image with jQuery ajax and manipulating and saving to server with intervention api

Tags: image, form-data, laravel-5.1, php-5.6, intervention

First of all let me explain simply what it is I am trying to achieve.

The user fills out a form and on submit I would like to send all the data with jQuerys $.post method and then with Laravel 5.1 and Intervention API(http://image.intervention.io/) I would like to process the data and upload the image to the correct directory on the server.

My data does send to the server(local) and I am able to read it all using Laravels Input class, I think the problem lies with the way I am using Intervention however I can't be certain.

Here is the relevant JS I have for the form(removed irrelevant code):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

var State = {
    CurrentCategorySelected: 1
}

var URIROOT = '/administrator/';

$(document).on('click', '.ModalSave', function(e)
{   
  var fd = new FormData( $('.ProductForm').get(0) ),
        action = $(this).attr('data-saving');

    fd.append('category_id', State.CurrentCategorySelected);

    $.ajax({
        url: URIROOT+"new_product",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorMessage); 
        }
    }); 

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This JS seems to work just fine however I thought I would post it just so you know where the data originates.

Next my Laravel Route is as follows:

```
Route::post('new_product', 'Admin\ProductManagerController@saveNewProduct');
```

And the relevant PHP in the controller is as follows(removed irrelevant code):

```
    <?php namespace TottonTimber\Http\Controllers\Admin;

    use View;
    use Image;
    use Input;
    use DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use TottonTimber\Http\Requests;
    use TottonTimber\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use TottonTimber\Category;
    use TottonTimber\Product;

  class ProductManagerController extends Controller {
    public function saveNewProduct() 
    {
        /*
         * Define Varibles
         */
        $input = Input::all();
        $image = Input::file('main_image');
        $image_name = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $imageDir = public_path('img/catalogue/products/' . $image_name);
        $imageDirSmall = public_path('img/catalogue/products/small_thumbs/' . $image_name);
        $imageDirMedium = public_path('img/catalogue/products/medium_thumbs/' . $image_name);
        $imageDirLarge = public_path('img/catalogue/products/large_thumbs/' . $image_name);
        /*
         * Save the Image and all of its resized siblings
         */     
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($imageDir);    
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(null, 100, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($imageDirSmall);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($imageDirMedium);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(null, 400, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($imageDirLarge);

        /*
         * Create a new entry in the database for the new product
         */
        $product = new Product;                       
        $product->description = $input['description'];    
        $product->content = $input['content'];      
        $product->price = $input['price'];      
        $product->product_code = $input['code'];    
        $product->main_image = $image_name;
        $product->status = 'enabled';
        $product->save();

        /*
         * Create the Relationship to its category
         */
        DB::table('category_product')->insert([
            'category_id' => $input['category_id'],
            'product_id' => $product->id
        ]);
    }
  }
```

The code breaks where the first "Image::make.." function is ran so I am not sure if this is because I am passing incorrect data or what.

If I var_dump some some things so you can see the output:

**$image**

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#27 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(23) "22mm Sawn Whitewood.jpg"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**$image->getRealPath()**

```
string(52) "C:\Users\alex\Documents\websites\TottonTimber\public"
```

**$imageDir**

```
string(109) "C:\Users\alex\Documents\websites\TottonTimber\public/img/catalogue/products/143869677322mm Sawn Whitewood.jpg"
```

What is it I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Okay I have just made a revelation, after trying random other images out of frustration one worked. I have now found that Images with uppercase or spaces were causing the code to break.

Comment: I was mistaken this has resolved nothing as I now run the name through str_replace for spaces to underscores, but still it fails, but only on certain images .jpg images but there are other .jpg images that work????

Comment: Okay it would seem I have the answer the images that did not work happened to all be over 2M which happened to be the upload_max_filesize in PHP, I have now edited that PHP setting and it works just fine.